# Adding few Sql Server Standard Edition dlls in express edition. Would this terminate li

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I was reading a topic in a book regarding sending database mail in sql server. But I found that in express edition DatabaseMails is not available.

So I started googling and found the link to enable database mail in sql server express edition.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/07/01/60245.aspx

In this article it was written "Now the only problem with this is that you have to get those 3 files from either standard or enterprise edition of SQL Server". Would this terminate license agreement of Sql Server express edition or it can be used in production without terminating license.

Comment: You need to consult your license to find out. These vary from country to country, so there's no one answer.

Comment: If you read the EULA I"m sure that it states that modifying, reverse engineering, etc., etc. is a violation of the EULA.

Comment: Besdes the EULA problem - DatabaseMail is a bad approahc to sending mails to start with. So you breach the law for having a bar architecture? OUCH.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a license for standard or enterprise then using the dlls from it is a breach of copyright in pretty much any country.  Your express licence gives you no right to them whatsoever.

It is only if you do have licence to use standard/enterprise but want to use express for some other reason then you need to check the terms of that licence.